# Angular 5 - add style to specific element dynamically

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-template

I am using Angular 5.2 in my project and new to the angular framework. My component html is looking like this:-

[image]

I want to add the style="top:200px;" dynamically to the highlighted element with class="app-alerts" in the above screenshot in the angular ts code. The div element with class "app-alerts" get added to the DOM on the render.

Please suggest the code changes.

Comment: is this going to be based on some condition?

Comment: There is no condition at the moment. Please suggest the code changes.

Comment: you can directly use `document.querySelector('app-alerts').style="top:200px"`

Comment: Which event would be appropriate for it ? ngAfterViewInit

Comment: if it is going to be a child component then use `ngAfterViewInit` or `ngAfterContentInit`

Comment: ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        document.querySelector('app-alerts').style = "top:200px";               
    }  gives red-error lines in vs.net. It says style does not exist on type 'Element'

Comment: Gives typescript error TypeError: Cannot set property 'style' of null

Comment: The syntax might be wrong I guess watch the return types please.

Comment: I got the right syntax now. Thanks Aravind !

Comment: ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        (document.querySelector('.app-alerts') as HTMLElement).style.top = '150px';
        
    }

Comment: You can move the answer to the correct section. And then i can select this as an answer.

Comment: OP -- Is there a reason you don't prefer [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846248/1028230) from @ChrisStanley? That seems to be the "Angular Way" to solve your issue, afaict.

Comment: Chris replied in August and i got the earlier solution in June. His solution is neat as well.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As per our comments, You should be using `document.querySelector` after a life cycle hook

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    (document.querySelector('.app-alerts') as HTMLElement).style.top = '150px';
}
```

Comment: When you need to reach a native element, consider using "Template reference variables" https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var . For specific dynamic style, prefer @chris-stanley anwser

Comment: This is not solution for angular, thus the down vote.

Comment: No, this is a really bad practice

Comment: If this is bad practice then how we can apply style to a class which is present in a third party control dynamically in Angular way?

Comment: Also use of `document` makes this not SSR compatible

Comment: I settled on this solution as nothing seemed to work for setting width of the component inserted in the router outlet into mat-sidenav-content

Answer (score 100):

I'm super late to this party, but NO! DO NOT USE DOCUMENT.QUERYSELECTOR. That is NOT how you style an Angular DOM element!

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'top.px': divStyle}">
```

Then in your component, you have

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.divStyle = 200; 
}
```

Comment: Can you not do `<div [style.top]="'200px'">` ?

Comment: @Ben You can even do `<div [style.top.px]="variableTopHeight">`! If you wanted to inline the value, you could `<div [style.top.px]="'200'">`

Comment: looks neat. but how you will apply style to a class which is present in a third party control dynamically in Angular way?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a page that has good explanation and sample code to add the style dynamically in Angular 2+.
[Attach the style dynamically in Angular](https://codeburst.io/how-to-add-styles-in-angular-e6918228eff2)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i needed to scroll a div when user scroll a page, and solved my problem with the code below.
At the component where you want to capture the scroll:

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('curtain') divCurtain: ElementRef;

export class ComponentX {
    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event) {
        console.log(window.pageYOffset);
        this.divCurtain.nativeElement.style.top = window.pageYOffset.toString().concat('px');
    }

    ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

Only this, i did not create any directive or other code.
This `HostListener` is executed every time the user scroll the page, and i get the `window.pageYOffset` to send to my div.

I hope it helps.